# Uninstalling IBM DB2 Express C

Tags: db2

I'm trying to uninstall IBM DB2 Express C in Windows 7. The uninstaller completed successfully (removed files, users, etc) but the databases which I created were not removed. I still have about 1GB of database files in C:\DB2\NODE0000. How do I also remove the databases?

PS: DB2 is now uninstalled. DB2 drop database command will not work now right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uninstaller doesn't know if you're removing it for reinstallation purposes, so it doesn't automatically delete databases that you created.  You don't have a `db2` command available anymore, so you have to remove it manually.

Since DB2 is completely uninstalled, you can simply remove the files by dragging the `C:\DB2` directory to the trash and emptying it.  (You may want to ensure that there aren't any files like you created manually in the directory, though).

You may also want to look for additional files that may have been left in `C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2`.